# Postgresql not using index for queries using CURRENT_USER

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a Postgresql table:

```sql
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS acls1k (
    pkey serial PRIMARY KEY,
    user_name VARCHAR(50),
    tenant_id VARCHAR(36),
    CONSTRAINT user_name_unique1k UNIQUE (user_name)
  );
```

There is a `unique` index on the user_name column. When I query the table using a constant, the **index** is used for the query:

```sql
explain analyze select * from acls1k where user_name = 'p1kuser1t1';
                                                         QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using user_name_unique1k on acls1k  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=53) (actual time=0.071..0.073 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((user_name)::text = 'p1kuser1t1'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.240 ms
 Execution Time: 0.094 ms
(4 rows)
```

but when I use the `current_user` variable a **sequential scan** is performed instead of index scan:

```sql
explain analyze select * from acls1k where user_name = current_user;
                                            QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on acls1k  (cost=0.00..59.00 rows=1 width=53) (actual time=0.162..0.845 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: ((user_name)::text = CURRENT_USER)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 999
 Planning Time: 0.097 ms
 Execution Time: 0.861 ms
(5 rows)
```

Tried casting:

```sql
explain analyze select * from acls1k where user_name = CAST(current_user as varchar(50));
explain analyze select * from acls1k where user_name = CAST(current_user as text);
explain analyze select * from acls1k where user_name = current_user::text;
```

But still, a sequential scan is used, not really sure why I see this behavior, any way to make this query use an index scan?

**Edit:**
**Can anyone answer why inline casting from `name` datatype to `varchar` fails?**

@jimjonesbr gave an answer on how to use an index scan using `prepared statements`. I speculate the problem is with the query planner not handling the datatype conversion properly.

I have tried to use a function instead of a prepared statement but was unable to run explain analyze to check index scan is performed. what I was able to notice is that runtime is faster when passing `current_user` as a `varchar` parameter instead of using it inline which might suggest index scan is used.

```sql
create function get_acl(auser varchar(63))
returns varchar(36)
language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
        return (select tenant_id from acls1k where user_name = auser);
end;
$$;


create function get_acl_inline()
returns varchar(36)
language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
        return (select tenant_id from acls1k where user_name = current_user);
end;
```

and running with `explain analyze` produce this:

```sql
explain analyze select from get_acl(current_user::text);
                                              QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on get_acl  (cost=0.26..0.27 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.435..0.436 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.027 ms
 Execution Time: 0.456 ms
(3 rows)

explain analyze select from get_acl_inline();
                                                 QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Function Scan on get_acl_inline  (cost=0.25..0.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=1.833..1.834 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.024 ms
 Execution Time: 1.850 ms
```

the time difference might suggest index scan is preform in `get_acls(current_user::text)`

Comment: Without the cast to `text` or `varchar` types, the seq scan is expected because `current_user` is of type `name`, which has different comparison semantics. With the cast it should work, make sure you have analyzed the table if it's freshly populated.

Comment: @DanielVérité I'm still trying to understand this. It seems that casting does not suffice: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8qX2tbtU3tNH1U6QsVTyaf/3  what am I missing?

Comment: @JimJones: your example is very different because its inserts 1 million times the same user whereas darc has a unique constraint on that column. An index might not be used by postgres to find a constant if the stats say that this constant is extremely frequent (the index is counterproductive in that case)

Comment: @DanielVérité I get that, but my point is rather: why does it use the index using a prepared statement, although it is a bad idea? I mean, the data is the same for both queries .. I'm a bit confused, and sorry I am bothering :)

Comment: @DanielVérité see: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8qX2tbtU3tNH1U6QsVTyaf/6

Comment: Simple functions like that are better defined as `language sql stable` - then you can also see the full execution plan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name tried using sql stable but couldn't see what execution plan for scanning acls table.
CREATE FUNCTION stable_get_acl(varchar(63)) RETURNS varchar(36)
    AS 'select tenant_id from xaclz where user_name = $1;'
    LANGUAGE SQL STABLE
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly don't understand this behaviour either - although there might be a good reason for that. I'll put down some thoughts and we can get the discussion started.

Perhaps it's the casting from `name` to `text` that does not work as we expect, no matter if the `name` parameter comes from a session information function or not. :

**Test 1**: casting `CURRENT_USER` to `text`:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE,COSTS OFF) 
SELECT * FROM acls1k WHERE user_name = CURRENT_USER::text; 

Gather (actual time=252.261..252.312 rows=0 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on acls1k (actual time=234.139..234.140 rows=0 loops=3)
        Filter: (user_name = (CURRENT_USER)::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 333333
Planning Time: 0.262 ms
Execution Time: 252.328 ms
```

**Test 2**: casting a `name` string to text in the `WHERE` clause:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE,COSTS OFF) 
SELECT * FROM acls1k WHERE user_name = 'myuser'::name::text; 

Gather (actual time=200.262..200.321 rows=0 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on acls1k (actual time=180.093..180.094 rows=0 loops=3)
        Filter: (user_name = 'myuser'::text COLLATE "C")
        Rows Removed by Filter: 333333
Planning Time: 0.043 ms
Execution Time: 200.334 ms
```

**Test 3**: Casting from `name` to `text` in a CTE:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE,COSTS OFF) 
WITH u (uname) AS (SELECT CURRENT_USER::text)
SELECT * FROM acls1k a 
JOIN u ON a.user_name = u.uname; 

Gather (actual time=229.228..229.280 rows=0 loops=1)
  Workers Planned: 2
  Workers Launched: 2
  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on acls1k a (actual time=208.065..208.066 rows=0 loops=3)
        Filter: (user_name = (CURRENT_USER)::text)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 333333
Planning Time: 0.085 ms
Execution Time: 229.293 ms
```

However, we can sort of process this casting *prior* to the query, so that the planer already sees the parameter as `text`. An alternative is to use a [`PREPARED STATEMENT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) (or a function as you suggested). In the following example we create a statement that has a `text` parameter, so that if there is a casting it should happen *"before"* the query runs:

```
PREPARE pu (text) AS SELECT * FROM acls1k WHERE user_name = $1;

EXPLAIN (ANALYSE,COSTS OFF) 
EXECUTE pu(CURRENT_USER);

                                QUERY PLAN                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using idx on acls1k (actual time=0.078..0.079 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (user_name = 'myuser'::text)
 Planning Time: 10.607 ms
 Execution Time: 0.095 ms
(4 rows)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f955ce0d2dd2144e4e45032ffff42bda)

Comment: thanks, @jimjonesbr this actually answers the question of how to use an index scan but doesn't answer why inline conversion of current_user fails. what was your intuition for using prepared statements? I actually tried using functions to force casting before running the query but got stuck trying to run explain analyze.

Comment: @darc I'm also struggling to find an answer for that behaviour. I edited my answer with more details and tests, so that we have a better ground to look for the problem. I do suspect that the casting from `name` to `text` might be the issue here. I guess we'll need to read the postgresql source code to be definitely sure

Answer (score 0):

If the collation of your column and `current_user` mismatch the index will not be used. Please check the collation of your `user_name` column and cast `current_user` accordingly.

```
explain analyze select * from acls1k where user_name = current_user::text COLLATE "default";

                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                       
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using username_idx on acls1k  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=212) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((user_name)::text = ((CURRENT_USER)::text)::text)
 Planning Time: 0.232 ms
 Execution Time: 0.058 ms
```